# Como fazer rollback na transação utilizando using?

Tags: c#

Como posso dar `RollBack()` em uma transação iniciada na declaração `using`?

Sei que consigo deixar a variável da transação fora do `using` do `SqlConnection`, mas é possível `RollBack()` usando o `using`?

Meu código

```
        using (SqlConnection cnn = Geral.conexaoSql())
        using (SqlTransaction tran = cnn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _clienteBLL.ApagarCliente(cliente, cnn, tran);

            tran.Commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar um bloco `try` `catch` e dentro do `catch` chamar o método `RollBack` do `SQLTransaction`:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = Geral.conexaoSql())
using (SqlTransaction tran = cnn.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        _clienteBLL.ApagarCliente(cliente, cnn, tran);

        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        tran.RollBack();
    }
}
```